# How can I view 1 result per line, whether the 2 rows and 2 columns match?

Tags: sql, database, vertica

```
SELECT ID, YEAR, C1, C2 
FROM test_table
```

| ID | YEAR | C1 | C2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2018 | 1 | 1 |

How can I write a SQL statement that shows me if the ones are matching for both years for each column?

I am thinking of something like that but this is wrong

```
CASE 
    WHEN (YEAR = 2018 AND C1 = 1) = (YEAR = 2019 AND C1 = 1) 
        THEN 'matching records' 
        ELSE 'not matching' 
END AS C1_Decision
```

I would like to achieve the following result

| ID | YEAR | C1_Decision |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019 | Matching |
| 1 | 2018 | Matching |

Comment: Is it always just two records returned that are being compared or would there be 3 or more rows returned also and they all have to be compared (or maybe just their immediate next and prior year?)?

Comment: So there are going to be years 2020 and 2021 added later. Thus, I believe yes, they have to be compared to the previous year. Basically what I am trying to achieve is to - compare the records of this year against the previous year if they match then print match

Answer (score 0):

[`LAG()`](https://www.vertica.com/docs/10.0.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/Analytic/LAGAnalytic.htm) and [`LEAD()`](https://www.vertica.com/docs/10.0.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/Analytic/LEADAnalytic.htm) can help here:

To test if the previous year matches the current record:

```
SELECT ID, YEAR, CASE WHEN C1 = LAG(C1) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY YEAR) THEN 'Matching' ELSE 'Not Matching'
FROM test_table
```

If you are interested, these foot into a wider range of functions called "Window Functions" that can be very handy for aggregating and comparing other rows in the result set based on partitions of data within that result set: https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/AnalyzingData/SQLAnalytics/WindowPartitioning.htm

Comment: Great Answer! Thank you so much. One more question, would I need to re-crease the case statement for every C# I have?

Comment: Yes. There is no way in SQL to dynamically reference a database object (table, view, column, procedure, function, etc). You have to be specific.